# Take a snapshot of using the rectangle in WP7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, bitmap, writeablebitmap

Im working on a WP7-app where I would like to record video and before the video is saved take a snapshot of the video so that it could be used as a thumbnail picture. The thumbnail picture is temporary save in the isolated storage before it is used. For the camera I use a rectangle to record video and later I want to display the picture on the phone.
The problem is that the picture is displays only a black screen. Even when i tried to save the picture in the media library the picture is also there displayed as black. What can be the cause of this problem and how do i solve it?

I inserted the code below:

Here is the rectangle where you capture the video with.

```
 <Rectangle 
            x:Name="viewfinderRectangle"
            Width="640" 
            Height="480" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Canvas.Left="80"/>
```

Here is the code for taking the picture:

```
try
            {
                String tempJPEG = FOSConstants.TEMP_VIDEO_THUMBNAIL_NAME;
                var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                if (myStore.FileExists(tempJPEG))
                {
                    myStore.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
                }
                IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(tempJPEG);

                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(viewfinderRectangle, null);
                wb.SaveJpeg(myFileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
                myFileStream.Close();

                myFileStream.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error saving snapshot", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
```

Here is the code for reading the thumbnail picture from the isolated storage:

```
private BitmapImage GetIsolatedStorageFile(string isolatedStorageFileName)
{
        var bimg = new BitmapImage();
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
           using (var stream = store.OpenFile(isolatedStorageFileName, FileMode.Open,                 FileAccess.Read))
            {  
                bimg.SetSource(stream);
            }
        }


return bimg;    
}
```

Here is the image where I want to display my thumbnail in the GUI.

```
<Image Width="180" 
                       Height="180" 
                       Stretch="Fill"
                       Margin="24,0,0,0"
                       Source="{Binding Path=ImageSoruce, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: removed misleading stuff about Invalidate() you dont need to do that.

So you can use the GetPreviewBufferArgb32() method to get what the camera is providing at the moment. This can be copied to your writable bitmap as show below.

```
using (var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (myStore.FileExists(tempJPEG))
    {
        myStore.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
    }

    IsolatedStorageFileStream file = myStore.CreateFile(tempJPEG);
    int[] buf = new int[(int)c.PreviewResolution.Width * (int)c.PreviewResolution.Height];
    c.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(buf);

    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((int)c.PreviewResolution.Width, (int)c.PreviewResolution.Height);
    Array.Copy(buf, wb.Pixels, buf.Length);
    wb.SaveJpeg(file, (int)c.PreviewResolution.Width, (int)c.PreviewResolution.Height, 0, 100);
}
```

The reason your sample code does not work is that the viewfinder brush is set up on the GPU (I think I can remember why I think it is done there, but I think it is). This means that silverlight does not have access too the raw video and when you render the silverlight element, it is blank (as though it has no background).

Comment: Sorry - misleading stuff todo with Invalidate(). Have updated answer to use GetPreviewBufferArgb32() instead.

Comment: What is 'c' in your example? as in "c.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(buf);" It is not declared or instantiated

Comment: I found that c is a type of PhotoCamera but in my case I'm using "CaptureSource _captureSource".

Comment: MSDN says you can capture a frame using CaptureImageAsync (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.capturesource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Sorry never used this, I've only used the PhotoCamera